# send HTML email from a spreadsheet using a different alias

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-email

I've been frolicking around sending emails from Google Spreadsheet.

The sent email has two requirements to fill:

- It needs to be send from my work-alias
- It needs to be as HTML

I can do the former with:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,body,{from:alias,replayTo:alias})
```

*Given a proper definition of 'alias', that works very well.*

I can do the latter with:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,"",{htmlBody:body})
```

But, perhaps you guessed it:

- GmailApp doesn't seem to support the HTMLBody option,
- MailApp doesn't seem to be able to send e-mail from an alias.

Did I do something wrong? Did I search the wrong place? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both API's, GmailApp and MailApp, have the possibility to send a HTML body via the advanced options. I used below code and was able to send HTML formatted text through both of them.

### Code

```
// global var 
var html =  
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2> Test </h2><br />' +
        '<p> Greetings Earthling </p>' +
    '</body>'    

function testGmailApp() {  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    'your@emailaddress.com',         // recipient
    'test GmailApp',                 // subject 
    'test', {                        // body
      htmlBody: html                 // advanced options
    }
  ); 
}

function testMailApp() {
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    'your@emailaddress.com',         // recipient
    'test MailApp',                  // subject 
    'test', {                        // body
      htmlBody: html                 // advanced options
    }
  ); 
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Reference

- GmailApp: [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app?hl=en#sendEmail%28String,String,String%29)
- MailApp:  [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29)

Comment: Thank you! It works wonder well, even with the from: advanced option. I really have no clue what I did wrong in the first place.